# Xamarin.Forms: CollectionView v/s ListView v/s TableView

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to display content of a book in my Xamarin Forms app. For the time being, I used `ListView`. But the `ListView` cannot have multiple data items bound to single row.

In `ListView`, I could make as below:

**`Sl No`**
**`Chapter`**
**`Page No`**

But I need the data as follows:

**`Sl No      Chapter      Page No`**

And I need the above header to be shown always. And the data may be furnished with backgrounds.

Now, I checked `CollectionView` and `TableView`, and I confused to choose in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as docs say, TableVies has no ItemsSource, so you have to manually insert everything. I would recommend CollectionView, it has a lot of useful stuff like aligning items vertically or horizontally and much more.

If you want header, just use CollectionView.Header (and also Footer) and play around.

Comment: @ Andreja, I also read that the ```CollectionView``` is more faster than ```ListView```